# WPF Combobox SelectedIndex Not Working

Tags: wpf, combobox, selecteditem

I have a WPF user control (FileSelectionView.xaml) with a combo box that displays data.  My WPF looks like:

```
<ComboBox Width="250"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FileTypes}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=FileType, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

In my View Model file (FileSelectionViewModel.cs), I have a List that binds to this control that successfully works.  The data looks like:

```
<Please select a file>
File Type 1
File Type 2
```

I have tried to set the `SelectedIndex` property to 0 so that "<Please select a file>" shows up when the user control renders, but it is not working.  It doesn't show anything, but when I click on the combo box, I do see all my items.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: After changing the selected Index did you notify the view with RaisePropertyChanged event

Comment: I tried to set the selected index in the xaml.  Would your question still apply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `SelectedIndex`, After updating the `ItemsSource`, update the selected item with the following code from viewmodel

```
FileType = "Please select a value";
```

Comment: To clarify for others, instead of binding to the selected index, just initialize the SelectedItem's binding property (in this case, FileType) to the appropriate item in the combo box (e.g. FileTypes[0] or whatever your "default" object is).

Answer (score 1):

IT works just fine, if you do it in XAML, I don't see it in your XAML, did you forget?

```
 <ComboBox Width="250"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FileTypes}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding Path=FileType, Mode=TwoWay}" 
          SelectedIndex="0"/>
```

Note that only will work initially, then you'll have to reset it again when you need it.. via trigger, or code behind.